# NullPointerException when using MediatorLiveData

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, mediatorlivedata

I would like to display a sortable list of restaurants. It worked when I was using a simple LiveData, but I get a NullPointerException since I changed it for a mediatorLiveData.

In the fragment, i use these lines to observe the mediatorLiveData

```
vm.getAllRestaurantsWithOrderMediatorLD().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), listRestaurants -> {
            datas.clear();
            datas.addAll(listRestaurants);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        });
```

And here the viewmodel class :

```
public class ListRestaurantsViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private final RestaurantRepository restaurantRepository;
    private final SortRepository sortRepository;
    private final MutableLiveData<List<RestaurantViewState>> allRestaurantsViewStateLD = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private final MutableLiveData<SortRepository.OrderBy> orderLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private final MediatorLiveData<List<RestaurantViewState>> allRestaurantsWithOrderMediatorLD;

    Context ctx;

    public ListRestaurantsViewModel(RestaurantRepository restaurantRepository, SortRepository sortRepository, Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.restaurantRepository = restaurantRepository;
        this.sortRepository = sortRepository;

        allRestaurantsWithOrderMediatorLD = new MediatorLiveData<>();
        allRestaurantsWithOrderMediatorLD.addSource(getAllRestaurantsViewStateLD(), value -> allRestaurantsWithOrderMediatorLD.setValue(value));

        allRestaurantsWithOrderMediatorLD.addSource(getOrderLiveData(), order -> {
                                                       
                      List<RestaurantViewState> restaurants = getAllRestaurantsViewStateLD().getValue();
                      if (restaurants != null && !restaurants.isEmpty()) {
                      List<RestaurantViewState> newList = new ArrayList<>();
                      if (order == SortRepository.OrderBy.DISTANCE)
                                                                newList =
                                                                        Stream.of(restaurants).sorted((a, b) -> a.getDistance() - b.getDistance()).toList();

                     else if (order == SortRepository.OrderBy.RATING)
                                                                newList = Stream.of(restaurants).sorted((a, b) -> Double.compare(a.getStarsCount(),
                                                                                                                                 b.getStarsCount())).toList();

         allRestaurantsWithOrderMediatorLD.setValue(newList);
        }
    }
);
    }

    public MediatorLiveData<List<RestaurantViewState>> getAllRestaurantsWithOrderMediatorLD() {
        return allRestaurantsWithOrderMediatorLD;
    }

    public LiveData<SortRepository.OrderBy> getOrderLiveData() {
        return sortRepository.getOrderLiveData();
    }

    public LiveData<List<RestaurantViewState>> getAllRestaurantsViewStateLD() {
        return Transformations.map(restaurantRepository.getRestaurantsLiveData(), restaurantsList -> {
            List<RestaurantViewState> restaurantViewStates = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Restaurant r : restaurantsList) {

                restaurantViewStates.add(new RestaurantViewState(
                                                 r.getId(),
                                                 r.getName(),
                                                 r.getType(),
                                                 r.getAdress(),
                                                 r.getImage()
                                         )
                                        );
            }
            return restaurantViewStates;
        });
    }
```

This is the error, I get
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.observeForever(androidx.lifecycle.Observer)' on a null object reference`

I have no error if I observe the livedata getAllRestaurantsViewStateLD() in the fragment, so I think I did not get something in the use of mediatorLiveData
Do you see what it is?

Answer (score 0):

The crash is on the call to `observeForever`, but your code snippet doesn't show you are using it. So the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I am not sure what the observeForever is. I don't use it anywhere.

Comment: AFAIK observeForever is called internally by mediator live data, if OP posted his exception stack instead of lone error message then maybe it'd be possible to determine which line of his own code triggered it.

Comment: The line mentionned in the error message is related to this function `void plug() {
            mLiveData.observeForever(this);
        }` in MediatorLiveData.java

Comment: @Emmcy well in such case `mLiveData` is null. Try to understand why is it happening.

Comment: What seems weird to me, is that it works with one of its sources (there is no crash if I observe the  1st LiveData). I don't get how the mediatorLiveData can be null if its source isn't